# What's the easiest way to display an image in C/Linux?

Tags: c, linux, image, graphics

I'm quite comfortable with C for numerical computation, but not for graphical programming.  I have a Nx by Ny by 3 RGB matrix in a command-line program for linux (gcc, ubuntu) and I want to pop up a window with it as an image. What's the easiest way to do this?  It has to be relatively quick because I'll be updating the image frequently.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Here is how to display and image with Gtk2 using C.  You can find more information (including a [tutorial](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk-tutorial/stable/)) on the [Gtk2](http://www.gtk.org/documentation.html) site.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void destroy(void) {
  gtk_main_quit();
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  GtkWidget* window;
  GtkWidget* image;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);


  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  image  = gtk_image_new_from_file(argv[1]);

  gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT (window), "destroy",
             GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (destroy), NULL);

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), image);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Here is how to compile it:

```
gcc -Wall img.c -o img `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using image magick it seems to have a function for displaying an image to an x window with a minimal amount of work. I have used image magick in the past and have been pleased with it. I have not tried this specific function though.

[Display function](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/display.php)

Comment: Seconded.  ImageMagick is probably the easiest way to do this from C.

Answer (score 1):

The C language itself doesn't have any built-in graphics capability.  You can use a graphics toolkit like Qt, gtk, wxWidgets, etc.  You could also construct an image file ([BMP is pretty simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)), and then launch (using fork and exec) an application to view it.  Ubuntu uses gnome by default, you could fork "gnome-open" with a command-line argument that is the name of the file you created, and gnome-open will then launch whichever application is associated with the file type.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like maybe you're doing some scientific computing and just need a quick way to display results.

Something like [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) may give you better mileage than learning a generic windowing toolkit. It's a general plotting utility and specifically geared towards displaying data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the image to a pixmap, create an X window (or allocate a framebuffer), and write the pixmap to the window.

Or, look at ImageMagick's implementation of the `display` command.

If you don't mind learning GTK+, then that might be the most straightforward way. Create a window and a drawable, and make the drawable a child of the window. Create a pixmap of your image and draw it to the drawable. Cairo will simplify this, since you'll only need to tweak your image format to make it work.

Comment: Qt is probably easier than GTK for a beginner to graphics programming... it's written in C++ but I think it has C bindings.

Answer (score 0):

The cairo graphics library is also a good way to go, see http://cairographics.org/ . It's cross platform, fairly efficient, and will let you work with Gnome/KDE/Windows or just generating image files fairly simply. It's designed for vectors, so also handles clipping, fonts and scaling well.